# How to skip particular text cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When I run below code how can I skip particular text cell from merging.

```
Original data
S.No.   Clock No.      01   02  03  04  05  06
1       099566          W   P   p   P   P   P
2       282420          P   P   P   W   P   P
3       623738          P   P   W   L   P   P
4       406290          P   P   W   P   P   P
5       792585          P   P   P   P   P   w
6       097608          P   P   P   P   w   P
```

after code running

```
S.No.   Clock No.      01   02  03  04  05  06
1       099566          W   P   p   P   P   P
2       282420          P   P   P   W   P   P
3       623738          P   pl  pl  pl  P   P
4       406290          P   P   cl  clP P   P
5       792585          P   P   P   P   P   w
6       097608          P   P   P   P   w   P
```

I need `w text cell` is constant or skipping when running code.

**code**

```
Sub LEAVE_MAP()
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    'Remember time when macro starts
    StartTime = Timer
    'Dim dtStartTime As Date
    'dtStartTime = Now()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("main"): Set ws2 = Sheets("leave")
    Dim firstAddr As String
    Dim Rno As Integer, c As Range, rngEmp As Range, StartD As Long, EndD As Long
    For Rno = 2 To 20
        For Each c In ws1.Range("F1:AJ1")
            Set rngEmp = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(ws1.Range("B" & Rno))
            If Not rngEmp Is Nothing Then
                firstAddr = rngEmp.Address
                Do
                    StartD = rngEmp.Offset(, 7)
                    EndD = rngEmp.Offset(, 8)
                    If c.Value >= StartD And c.Value <= EndD Then
                        ws1.Cells(Rno, c.Column) = ws2.Range("C" & rngEmp.Row)
                    End If
                    Set rngEmp = ws2.Range("A:A").FindNext(rngEmp)
                'Loop While Not (Rng Is Nothing) And Rng.Address <> firstAddress
                Loop While rngEmp.Address <> firstAddr
            End If
        Next c
    Next Rno

    'MsgBox "Macro ran successfully in " & _
      FormatDateTime(Now() - dtStartTime, 3), vbInformation
    ' MsgBox "Dear Boss Givened Task Completed Successfully. Have a Nice Day"
    Set c = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing: Set ws2 = Nothing
    'Determine how many seconds code took to run
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    'Notify user in seconds
    MsgBox "Dear Boss This code ran Successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not write question with all caps. The code can be formatted with the toolbar on top of the textbox.

Comment: It' unclear what you are asking for because you did not write (1) what your actually code does, (2) what it should do instead, (3) what goes wrong, (4) if there are any errors and where. [Edit] your question and make some of these points more clear.

Comment: IN EXCEL CELL WHEN I RUN CODE IF CELL VALUE IS EQUALS TO W WHEN THAT CELL SKIPPING IS REQUIRED

Comment: @PoleswaraVenkataRamanaRao (1) Again, don't write in all caps! This is unfriendly. (2) I asked you to [edit] your original question not to post a comment because the 4 points I mentioned cannot be answered in a one sentence comment. We need a **detailed** explanation! Otherwise we cannot help. Please answer all 4 points one by one.

Comment: How to Skip if cell text is equal to some text and run macro automatically.